# How to change style of dropped element using JqueryUI sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a pretty simple site in which I want to be able to drag and drop some styled DIV elements between two DIV containers. I have used JQueryUI's sortable function to successfully implement the drag and drop behavior like so:

```
$("#active-container").sortable({connectWith: "#inactive-container"});
$("#inactive-container").sortable({connectWith: "#active-container"});
```

I add my droppable DIV elements to the containers on button click using this method:

```
function createDeviceDiv (deviceObject, className){

  var div = document.createElement('div');

  div.id = deviceObject.deviceId;

  div.className = className + ' draggable="true"';

  div.textContent = deviceObject.deviceName;

  return div;
}
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.active-device-element
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  cursor: move;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 35px; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
}

.inactive-device-element
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
  background-color: floralwhite;
  cursor: move;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 35px; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
}

#active-container, #inactive-container
{
  background-color: lightgrey;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

The relevant portion of my index.html page (using Twitter bootstrap 3) is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h2>Active Devices</h2>
        <p>The following devices are currently listed as active.</p>
        <div id="active-container">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h2>Inactive Devices</h2>
        <p>The following devices are currently listed as inactive.</p>
        <div id="inactive-container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, dragging and dropping between the two containers works well. However, when dropped, the element retains the original style. I need to highlight changes that have been made by changing any element that has beeen drag dropped to a different background color/style, so based on my CSS, something like, '.modified-device-element'. I am unclear as to what the best way to accomplish this is.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI Sortable has several events you can use, one of them being [receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive). You can set up the event listener to get updates on both of the containers. Then, when items move from one to the other container you can get that item and modify it however you want, including adding another class.

```
$('#active-container, #inactive-container').on('sortreceive', function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.addClass('modified-device-element');
});
```

or when setting up the widget

```
$('#active-container').sortable({
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.addClass('modified-device-element');
    }
});

$('#inactive-container').sortable({
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.addClass('modified-device-element');
    }
});
```

Comment: As a side note, I am curious if it is possible to alter the text inside the dropped element? So in addition to changing it's class, I would like to update the element's text from "Device Name" to something like "Device Name (Modified)"?

Comment: Sure. You have access to jQuery object with ui.item so any of the methods you can use there will work. here's an example of getting the current text and updating it, `ui.item.html(ui.item.html() + ' Modified');`